# Why does dmenu block SIGINT propagation?

Tags: ide, dmenu, sigint

When running Jetbrains IDEs (such as PyCharm and Android Studio) through dmenu, I get the following warning:

> The IDE ignores SIGINT: the "Stop" button in run configurations may not work.

It then links [this support page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004770440) which says

> ...it's up to the user to change the way the IDE is launched so that the signal is not blocked (e.g. run from the terminal instead of the dmenu)`

**Why does dmenu cause this behavior? Is there a setting or a workaround available?**

---

After some testing to determine potential workarounds, I found I can run `pycharm&` in a terminal and close the terminal without issue or warning. However, if I make a script `run.sh` whose full contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash
pycharm&
```

When I run `run.sh` I get the SIGINT warning.